# How to set HELO/EHLO on Exim accordingly to match sending domain

Tags: smtp, exim

I have a VPS server, which is used to send emails. On that server I have 2 domain names attached and correctly configured with 2 different IP's.

DNS is set as well to match sending IP's accordingly:

```
mail.moneymattersforum.com mail.globe-forum.com
```

DNS A records for mail.* transparently reveals corresponding IP, so forward and reverse DNS resolutions match.

Everything seems good, and domains even deliver most of the time, however, the VPS hostname set to mail.moneymattersforum.com and Exim 4 uses it to advertise in HELO/EHLO upon ANY connection.

I've read and tried to fix this with + Exim restart:

```
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA=$sender_address_domain
```

and `smtp transport`'s ->

```
helo_data=$sender_address_domain
```

with no any luck, seems like the edits have no effect at all.

What I try to achieve: HELO/EHLO + SMTP banner should match the sending domain, eg if name@moneymattersforum.com sending => then HELO/EHLO should be mail.moneymattersforum.com AND if name@globe-forum.com sending -> then HELO/EHLO should match mail.globe-forum.com.

More information:

`/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` (generated by `updateconfexim` and copied):

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='moneymattersforum.com; globe-forum.com'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains='moneymattersforum.coml globe-forum.com'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

`/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` I've added these:

```
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_FROM_DNS='true'
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA=$sender_address_domain
```

`/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/00_local_settings`

```
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_FROM_DNS='true' REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA=$sender_address_domain`
```

`/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp/`:

```
debug_print = "T: remote_smtp for $local_part@$domain"
driver = smtp
helo_data = $sender_address_domain 
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA=$sender_address_domain
```

I see that `exim-update conf` says it's single file config, however just in case added everywhere. And it still have no effect. Also I've noticed that transport macros have a code to get domain from IP - to advertise in HELO, however nothing works - Exim only advertise hostname, alas.

added these lines to `/etc/exim4.conf` as well:

```
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_FROM_DNS='true' REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA=$sender_address_domain
HELO_DATA = "mail.${sender_address_domain}"
```

Nothing helps :-(

Please explain step by step how to generate new config for exim allowing HELO to be extracted from sending IP or domain name.  Thank you

Comment: Alex I've attempted to fix your question so that there's some formatting. Marking up the code makes the question more readable. Please would you [review it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/765106/edit) and correct anything I've omitted or got wrong.

Comment: Why? It's 2023. RMX is thoroughly deprecated. SPF handles the case properly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `dc_other_hostnames` should be colon-separated entries

Comment: symbcbean: No, unfortunately SPF not helps. mail-tester.com and some providers complain that HELO/EHLO mismatch, while a lot of covering everything SPF-rules in place

Comment: Chris Davies: This file was autogenerated by exim-conf, so I suppose it should be correct. However, this is unrelated to my issue. Thanks